# How to query in Spring boot thanks to the model constructors

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to retrieve an object Intervention, but my intervention are linked to other objects. When I retrieve only information from Intervention without making any link with the table Address for example then it works well. However I want to be able to only get the street name from the table Address and I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

```
@Repository
interface InterventionRepository : JpaRepository<Intervention, Long> {

@Query("select new Intervention(i.id, i.date, i.wishedDate, new Address(a.streetName1)) " +
        "from Intervention i " +
        "inner join i.address a ")
fun getInterventions(): Optional<ArrayList<Intervention>>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by myself, I was really doing it wrong.
I need to add the value of the address in my constructor. I made it work this way:

```
@Repository
interface InterventionRepository : JpaRepository<Intervention, Long> {

@Query("select new Intervention(i.id, i.date, i.wishedDate, a.name) " +
        "from Intervention i " +
        "inner join i.address a ")
fun getInterventions(): Optional<ArrayList<Intervention>>
}
```

And in my constructor I did it like this:

```
constructor(interventionId: Int?, date: Date?, addressName: String?) {

      this.id = interventionId
      this.date = date

      this.address = Address()
      this.address?.name = addressName
}
```

I don't know if it's the best solution but I made it work this way, I hope it can be helpful for someone else.